# How to do path operations on strings?

Tags: c++, stl

Say we have some string `A` "swdfsd/sdfsdf/sdfsd/sdfsd/sdf.file" and `B` "swdfsd/oooo/" and we want to  do some simple staff like  get folder neame where file is and get path to file A starting from location B (result like `swdfsd/oooo/../sdfsdf/sdfsd/sdfsd/sdf.file`)(not using boost::filesystem)?

Comment: Without `boost::filesystem` you're just going to have to manually parse the string.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward to write simple path routines like the equivalent of the Unix dirname and basename commands.  Those just deal with the last path separator of the path.

But as someone already commented, anything else can be tricky.  Consider the fact that using . and .. can complicate things.